# How to enable a plugin manager without ~/.vimrc

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

After using vim for some time now, my `~/.vim/` beginning with my first experiments with vim got really messy over time. So I thought, it would be time to tidy up and to begin with a plugin manager with a clean configuration.

Since I share my configuration over multiple machines, I usually manage my `~/.vim/` path with a git repo. To avoid a big .vimrc, I put my own configuration under `~/.vim/plugin/`. This allowed me, to keep all my shared configuration in this folder and to use `~/.vimrc` only for machine dependent configuration.

Starting with VAM over NeoBundle and now Vundle I have always the same problem. If I add the required configuration under `~/.vim/plugin/pluginmanager.vim` instead of `~/.vimrc`, the installed plugins do not load or were only partially loaded. The command `:echo &rtp` lists the correct bundles, but `:scriptnames` does not include the installed plugins. If I execute `mv ~/.vim/plugin/pluginmanager.vim ~/.vimrc` everythings works as expected.

Can anyone explain this behavior and perhaps offer a solution?

My `pluginmanager.vim` looks like this:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

My vim installation is version 7.4.52

Comment: Do you also not want to use `~/.vim/vimrc`?

Comment: Thanks, did not know about `~/.vim/vimrc`. Seems to be the best solution. Guess I have to update my question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the startup order. After your `~/.vimrc` has been executed (as the first thing during startup), Vim executes something like `:runtime! plugin/*.vim` to load the plugins. As your plugin manager is only then invoked, the changes in the `'runtimepath'` do not reach that triggering `:runtime` command any more, and the plugins fail to load.

There are many workarounds:

- Move your script to `~/.vim/pluginmanager.vim` and explicitly `:runtime pluginmanager.vim` it from (each copy of) your `~/.vimrc`.
- Re-trigger via `:runtime! plugin/*.vim`.

But I agree with @brettanomyces that the best solution would be to use `~/.vimrc` as intended, and place system-specific configuration into a different script instead.

Comment: Yes, that explains the behavior. Thanks for the insight. But as solution, I will use the `~/.vim/vimrc` like @FDinoff suggested in his comment. That is compatible with the version control system approach.

Comment: Yes, that's a good solution, provided you have current Vim versions on all systems, as this is a fairly recent feature.

Comment: Ah, good point. I tested the versions. The `:version` command was helpful, it lists, wich vimrc files are used.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `~/.vimrc` file for general configuration and having another file such as `~/.vimrc.local` with your machine specific configuration. You can source `~/.vimrc.local` by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc`.

```
if filereadable(glob("~/.vimrc.local")) 
    source ~/.vimrc.local
endif
```

Credit: http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/local-vimrc-files/

---

To solve your issue try adding `runtime! bundle/**/*.vim` to the end of your `pluginmanager.vim` file.

See also: `:help init`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sourcing other files is a nice way and a legitimate solution. But my intention is to avoid .vimrc. Without a plugin manager I did not missed it and my different configurations are better organized in the plugin directory. But it may be some sort of individual preference.

Comment: @Trendfischer: Just symlink `~/.vimrc` to something in your Git repo.